# Make HTTPPOST that includes data from main view and partialview in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http-post

Here is my situation:
Im currently making a website where it has to be possible to make a booking for renting a car.
My Index view contains the customer data and my partialview contains the car data. The Index view and the partial view makes use of two different models.
How do i make a httppost so i can create the correct booking with the data of both the customer and the car?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to create a ViewModel containing both the Customer data and the car data.

Something like:

```
class RentalViewModel
{
  public Car Car { get; set; }
  public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Your HttpPost method will then accept that:

```
class RentalsController
{
  [HttpPost]
  public Create(RentalViewModel model)
  {
    //abbreviated
    SaveLogic.SaveCar(model.Car);
    SaveLogic.SaveCustomer(model.Customer);
  }
}
```

You may need some custom model binding going on as well. But the ViewModel should probably be your first step.

Comment: Looks great! Will try it out now.